# Spring batch create several system calls

Tags: spring-batch

I am starting with spring batch and I have a code structure with list of objects, for each object I need to call an external ant process. I understand I can use the SystemCommandTasklet for this however I am not sure how to set it for multiple values (so far it seems it can only make 1 execution?) Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need Spring Batch for that? If you want to use Spring Batch you can create a chunk-oriented step where the reader returns items from the list, and an item processor that calls the procedure with a `java.lang.Process` for each item.

Comment: Spring batch does a lot stuff along the way, this will be another step among 10 or so, I believe I have to do it like you say